# Use of strptime for conversion

Tags: r, strptime

I am a beginner at date conversion and I have a character column in a data frame (say dataframe$date) as follows:

```
April-Friday-20
```

I am trying to use the following `strptime` code to convert to a date format in a new column (say `dataframe$column`), but am getting `NA`s in all rows. The number in the date stands for 24 hour time, with single digits.

```
dataframe$column <- strptime(dataframe$date,format="%B-%A-%k")
```

### Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Update: Some simple code to reproduce

```
datetest <- c("April-Friday-20")
datetest <- as.Date(datetest, format="%B-%A-%k")
```

Above code gives me NA

Comment: What is `str(dataframe$date)`? If anything other than character (e.g. factor) try wrapping in `as.character()`..?

Comment: Instead of `%k`, shouldn't it be `%d`, i.e. `strptime(dataframe$date,format="%B-%A-%d")`? `strptime("April-Friday-20", "%B-%A-%d")` gives `2015-04-20`.

Comment: Don't use `strptime` if you don't need a POSIXlt variable. Use `as.POSIXct` or in this case `as.Date`.

Comment: Thanks!  Pascal: The number in this case is a 24 hour time rather than date of month, which is why I tried to use %k.  beroe: str indicates it is a character vector. Roland: tried as.Date as well..still no go..I will update question with some simple code.

Comment: Update: Pascal: FYI, when I run this using "%B-%A-%d" it works, but I do not get a correct conversion ("2015-04-20") so seems the issue is with the %k for 24 hour time for NA at least.

Comment: A date **must** consist of a year, month and day. A datetime variable also must include those. You are missing a year and have no unambiguous day value.

Comment: Roland, thank you.  What you say is quite logical in review.  Am realizing that I cannot apply date to this structure as the "day" and "hour" is an aggregate for all four weeks in the month rather than a specific day and hour.  Will need to handle differently.  Thanks for straightening me out!